# how to change the width of a specific select2 if i am having more than 1 select2 in my html file?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having more than 1 select2 in my HTML file. I want to set a width to a specific select2 and a common width to all the other select2. The common width is affecting the width of all the select and even though if I am trying to override the width through jquery it is not happening.

CSS

```
.select2-container {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <select class="select2 form-control m-t-15"  id="user_name">
        <option selected="selected">Select Name</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select2 form-control m-t-15"  id="user_roll">
        <option selected="selected">Select Roll</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select2 form-control m-t-15"  id="user_address">
        <option selected="selected">Select Address</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
    $(".select2").select2();
    $("#user_address").select2({ width: '50%' });
```

Expected Result:-
select 2 of id "user_address" should be having width 50%.

Current Result:-
All the select 2 is having width 100%

Anybody any idea how to set 50% width to select2 of id "user_address"?

Comment: Hey Sweta, you can add a different class in the select box in which you want to set different height.

Comment: like how can you give an example

Answer (score 1):

You already have id's for each select2 
therefore u can style that specific select2 with its id
for ex let's  style 'user_roll':

```
#user_roll{
//your styling here, noting that "#" is for the id just like the "." is for class
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting option as selected use placeholder in select2

```js
$(".select2").select2({ width: '100%',placeholder:'Choose an Option', allowClear: true  });
$("#user_address").select2({ width: '60%' ,placeholder:'Choose an Address', allowClear: true });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="col-md-12">
    <select class="select2 form-control m-t-15"  id="user_name">
    </select>
    <select class="select2 form-control m-t-15"  id="user_roll"> 
    </select>
    <select class="select2 form-control m-t-15"  id="user_address">  
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just changes in css above your css code please remove it and replace with below code :

```
.select2 {
 width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#user_address{
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```css
.select-roll-width{
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <select class="select2 form-control m-t-15"  id="user_name">
        <option selected="selected">Select Name</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select2 select-roll-width form-control m-t-15"  id="user_roll">
        <option selected="selected">Select Roll</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select2 form-control m-t-15"  id="user_address">
        <option selected="selected">Select Address</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @sbrrk using jQuery we need to set. see the answer down